# How to make ToolStripDropDownButton items font bold?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I'm trying to format ToolStripDropDownButton items

```
btn1.DropDown.ForeColor = Color.Gray; //this works
btn1.DropDown.Font.Bold = true; //this doesn't work.
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the properties inside the Font are read-only. The solution is to create a new font, like this:

```
btn1.DropDown.Font = new Font(btn1.DropDown.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```